# Spark - 54 GB CSV file transform to single JSON in 16 GB RAM single machine

Tags: apache-spark

I want to take a CSV file and transform into single JSON, I have written and verified the code. I have a CSV file of 54 GB and I want to transform and export this single file into single JSON, I want to take this data in Spark and it will design the JSON using SparkSQL `collect_set(struct` built-in functions. 
I am running Spark job in Eclipse IDE in a single machine only. The machine configuration has 16 GB RAM, i5 Processor, 600 GB HDD.

Now when I have been trying to run the spark program it is throwing `java.lang.OutOfMemory` and insufficient heap size error. I tried to increase the `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` value `2000` to `20000` but still the job is failing after loading and during the transformation due to the same error I have mentioned.

I don't want to split the single CSV into multiple parts, I want to process this single CSV, how can I achieve that? Need help. Thanks.

**Spark Configuration:**

```
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("App10").setMaster("local[*]")
 //   .set("spark.executor.memory", "200g")
      .set("spark.driver.memory", "12g")
      .set("spark.executor.cores", "4")
      .set("spark.driver.cores", "4")
  //  .set("spark.testing.memory", "2147480000")
        .set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "20000")
        .set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "500g")      
        .set("spark.memory.offHeap.enabled", "true")
        .set("spark.memory.offHeap.size", "200g")
```

Answer (score 0):

Few observations from my side,

1. When you collect data at the end on driver it needs to have enough memory to hold your complete json output. 12g is not sufficient memory for that IMO.
2. 200g executor memory is commented then how much was allocated? Executors too need enough memory to process/transform this heavy data. If driver was allocated with 12g and if you have total of 16 then only available memory for executor is 1-2gb considering other applications running on system. It's possible to get OOM. I would recommend find whether driver or executor is lacking on memory
3. Most important, Spark is designed to process data in parallel on multiple machines to get max throughput. If you wanted to process this on single machine/single executor/single core etc. then you are not at all taking the benefits of Spark.

Not sure why you want to process it as a single file but I would suggest revisit your plan again and process it in a way where spark is able to use its benefits. Hope this helps.

Comment: Agree with you. Collect of data will that always be the Driver if repartition 1, or could be it selects a Worker to perform this? I ask as collect can occur on Worker as well I have noted.

Comment: So If I run the job in `--master yarn --deploy-mode client`  in a single server of 24 GB RAM. Then how much driver and executor memory is recommended? And also what should I set in Master instead of `.setMaster("local[*]")` ?

Comment: @thebluephantom, collect of worker happens when final result is not completely generated i.e. for intermediate stages. Final data in this case, complete json file will be collected at driver side.

Comment: Nobody will be able to say size of required cluster just based on size of input because important part is transformations which explode or reduce data. I think you need driver memory to contain complete json file atleast. executors can have less as they will read and process csv in chunks. Again don't try with single executor but give a shot with 2-3 executors with 5-6 gb of heap and then increase if you need to (if you get OOM or performance is not good like high GC). Keep in mind, Spark is memory intensive most of the time.